# Copying an SSH key to the server even though you are already using SSH

Tags: ssh, deployment, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have already copied an SSH key to a server with `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/skynet_key.pub`.

Now I am building the gitlab-ci pipeline and have generated an new SSH key pair on my computer. I saved the private key as a variable in my gitlab project account.

Now I want to upload the new public key to the server.

My question is can I do this again from my local computer with `ssh-copy-id`?

Because I already have an SSH key pair distributed on both systems.

Would there be any problems here?
If so, how can I transfer the public key to the server?
Manually add the pubKey to authorized_keys?

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](https://superuser.com/a/1264013/141), you can use the `-o` option (passed to SSH) to specify an existing key, in order to copy your second key:

```bash
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/<your-new-id-to-install> \
   -o 'IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your-already-existing-id>' \
   <servername>`
```